# Adjust vertical alignment of square brackets in equation

Tags: math-mode

Consider this MWE:

[image]

How can I adjust the vertical alignment of the square brackets so they are 'centered vertically' around the symbols? Notice how different the spacing is between the bottom of the bracket and the bottom of the symbols - compared to the top of the bracket and the top of the symbols. If this is conventional typographic style, then I am also happy to be told so!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
[\mathbf{K}-\omega^2\mathbf{M}]\bm{A}=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: contrary to what you say about vertical centering, the brackets *are* centered.  but they are centered around the "math axis" -- examine them with reference to the `=` sign.  if you had, for example, a `\gamma` or `\chi`, the effect would be much different.  this is indeed "conventional typographical style" for mathematics.

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right, I hadn't noticed this! Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

contrary to what you say about vertical centering, the brackets *are* centered. but they are centered around the "math axis".

examine them with reference to the = sign. if you had, for example, a \gamma or \chi, the effect would be much different.

this is indeed "conventional typographical style" for mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I think I've got your answer. Just use the `\raisebox{lift}{text}` to lift up the character.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\raisebox{1pt}{[} \mathbf{K}-\omega^2\mathbf{M} \raisebox{1pt}{]}\bm{A}=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: don't post multiple answers, you can edit your answer, or now you have two, delete the wrong one.  (this one is less wrong than the other, but `\raisebox` has lost the mathopen and mathclose horizontal spacing and (potentially) takes the brackets from a differnt font.