# Adjust vertical positioning of parenthesis

Tags: amsmath

I have a slight problem with some parenthesis enclosing unsymetrical stuff. For example, when you type

$$P\left(\overline D\right)$$

you notice that the parenthesis go a little bit too low under the $D$.

Is there a simple, AND automatic, way of dealing with this kind of stuff ? I noticed [Adjust vertical alignment of square brackets in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433996/adjust-vertical-alignment-of-square-brackets-in-equation), but it's really not satisfying if you have to type it everytime...

Thanks for any help.

\bye

Comment: You have tagged this amsmath but are you using plain tex rather than latex (`$$` and `\bye` would suggest so)? It usually helps if you provide a complete test document rather than a fragment. here I would simply not use `\left` and `\right`, Ithink.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the accepted answer of the question that you reference, you should not move the  delimiters away from the math axis.  The problem here is that `\left` `\right` makes the parenthesis too large (as well as introducing additional horizontal space). Just using a standard `(` produces a better effect both for the size and horizontal space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

aaa
\[P\left(\overline D\right)\]

bbb
\[P(\overline D)\]

\end{document}
```

see the discussion in

[Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173717/is-it-ever-bad-to-use-left-and-right)

Comment: I use LaTeX, with amsmath (\bye is just an old joke to sign my messages). And I don't find the bar over D being above the edge of the parenthesis... Maybe I'm too narrow minded ;-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS jokes are OK but since you also used `$$` which isn't LaTeX either, and didn't provide a latex test file (as in this answer) it seemed worth checking.

Comment: Sorry, I thought $$ was the standard way of writing maths on Tex.stackexchange...

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS the `$$P\left(\overline D\right)$$` in your question is an  example of tex source code (so would have been better marked as a code block (`{}` button in the editor) although it is plain tex rather than latex. unlike some other sites in the network this site does not use mathjax to render tex-like syntax as displayed mathematics.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS, regarding the use of `$$`, if you use the tag `amsmath`, you should use the `amsmath` syntax.  Maybe a review of the `amsmath` user guide would be helpful: `texdoc amsldoc`.